# Activeadmin custom filter fails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, filter, activeadmin

In activeadmin, we need to apply a kind of complicated filter on the index page of our Score model. Namely, we want to get the results in the `Score` table such that their `ExportOrder`s have the selected `DistributionChain`. We start from the following models:

```
class Score < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :export_orders, join_table: :scores_export_orders
end

class ExportOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :distribution_chain
  has_and_belongs_to_many :scores, join_table: :scores_export_orders
end

class DistributionChain < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :export_orders
end
```

In the schema.rb (excerpt):

```
  create_table "scores_export_orders", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "score_id"
    t.integer "export_order_id"
    t.index ["export_order_id"], name: "index_scores_export_orders_on_export_order_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["score_id"], name: "index_scores_export_orders_on_score_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "export_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "distribution_chain_id"
  end
```

In Score Activeadmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Score
  filter :delivery_distr_chain, as: :select, collection: DistributionChain.all
end
```

The scope of the filter is defined in the score model:

```
class Score < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  scope :delivery_distr_chain, -> (input) {
    self.joins(:export_orders).where('export_orders.distribution_chain_id = ?', input)
  }

  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:delivery_distr_chain]
  end
end
```

Following is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR:  table name "scores_export_orders" specified more than once
: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count_column) FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT "scores"."id" AS count_column FROM "scores" INNER JOIN "scores_export_orders" ON "scores_export_orders"."score_id" = "scores"."id" INNER JOIN "export_orders" ON "export_orders"."id" = "scores_export_orders"."export_order_id" LEFT JOIN scores_export_orders ON scores.id = scores_export_orders.score_id WHERE (NOT (scores_export_orders.score_id IS NULL)) AND (export_orders.distribution_chain_id = '2') LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)

activerecord (5.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:600:in `async_exec'
```

I sense that the query is not properly written. Can you tell us where we are failing?

---

**EDIT:** interesting to notice is the difference between executing the query in the rails console and within the scope in the `Score` model.

If I execute the same query in the rails console, it works without errors. The output of `Score.joins(:export_orders).where('export_orders.distribution_chain_id = ?', '2').to_sql` is:

`"SELECT \"scores\".* FROM \"scores\" INNER JOIN \"scores_export_orders\" ON \"scores_export_orders\".\"score_id\" = \"scores\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"export_orders\" ON \"export_orders\".\"id\" = \"scores_export_orders\".\"export_order_id\" WHERE (export_orders.distribution_chain_id = '2') ORDER BY \"scores\".\"created_at\" DESC"`

whereas the exact same query fails in the scope in the `Score` model, and the `.to_sql` output is:

`"SELECT DISTINCT \"scores\".* FROM \"scores\" INNER JOIN \"scores_export_orders\" ON \"scores_export_orders\".\"score_id\" = \"scores\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"export_orders\" ON \"export_orders\".\"id\" = \"scores_export_orders\".\"export_order_id\" LEFT JOIN scores_export_orders ON scores.id = scores_export_orders.score_id WHERE (NOT (scores_export_orders.score_id IS NULL)) AND (export_orders.distribution_chain_id = '2') ORDER BY \"scores\".\"id\" desc"`

The main difference lies in the left-join introduced by the scope: `LEFT JOIN scores_export_orders ON scores.id = scores_export_orders.score_id`, which lets specify the `scores_export_orders` table once more. I have no idea why this is introduced in there and not on the console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was not aware of the fact that I already declare a scope in my ActiveAdmin for Scores, which was the following:

`scope :exported, -> { joins("LEFT JOIN scores_export_orders ON scores.id = scores_export_orders.score_id").where.not("scores_export_orders.score_id IS NULL").distinct`

called in ActiveAdmin as

```
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.exported
    end
    ...
  end
```

---

Now I've rewritten the code such that I have in my score model:

```
class Score < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  scope :exported, -> { joins("INNER JOIN scores_export_orders ON scores.id = scores_export_orders.score_id INNER JOIN export_orders ON export_orders.id = scores_export_orders.export_order_id").where.not("scores_export_orders.score_id IS NULL").distinct }
  ...
  scope :delivery_distr_chain, -> (input) {
    self.where('export_orders.distribution_chain_id = ?', input)
  }

  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:delivery_distr_chain]
  end
end
```

so that I have the double join on the `exported` scope and I don't need to join again on the filter scope.